# How to Decode Laravel Passport access_token data in angular 6

Tags: angular, laravel

I have used passport authentication in Laravel 5.7 I have used Angular 6 as a front end. Now I need to decode the passport access token using Angular 6. I have searched it but every time I didn't got a proper solution. One of the solution is passport-jwt but there is no proper tutorial or documentation for it. Does anyone knows another solution or else proper tutorial for passport-jwt? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `decode access token`? Access token is an encoded key that can be decoded by the server created it. Laravel returns `access_token`, `refresh token` and `expires_in` values after creating the authentication. And which client type you are using?

Comment: I want to do it like we use jwt authentication. Like, Angular is providing jwt authentication. Is there any package at angular side to handle passport token.  @HarunYılmaz

Comment: I am also using Angular and Laravel in my project. I am not using any package so I cannot suggest any. I send credentials to server, retrieve tokens and store them in local storage. And with and angular http interceptor, I append them to every http call. Also I created a new token type that extends Laravel token to include user details with authentication response. But still I couldn't get the point why you want to `decode` the token.

Comment: See, I just have used jwt authentication and for that we need to decode the token everytime. So, I don't know how to handle it with passport access token. I thought we can handle it in same way! @HarunYılmaz

Comment: i'm not known about the Laravel Passwort access_token .. but I also have no clue why you want to decode in the frontend the token? JWT is meant to be decode on server level. decoding in frontend also means you need to decode with the same encryption key you use on the server when you encoded it. So then you need to expose the encryption key in your frontend code.

Answer (score -1):

you can create your custom token and to send it to angular front-end with success response:

```
$success['token'] = $user->createToken("AcesssToken")->accessToken';
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want to do it will passport token only! @Ajay Malhotra